# SSH into Linux VM on Azure using cloud shell

Tags: azure, ssh, azure-cloud-shell

I would love to use the Azure cloud shell to SSH into my Linux VMs on Azure, they don't have a public IP and they are on a Virtual Network.  Does anyone know of a way I can do this?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: This might help. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/ssh-from-windows               Also, Add some details about the problem you are facing and what you have tried till now.Clear questions with all the necessary points would improves your chances of getting good answers

Comment: This is possible by dynamically updating the related NSG rule.  This link provides a great example: http://www.fhtino.it/blog/workaround-for-connecting-ssh-source-ip-protected-vm-from-azure-cloud-shell

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) or [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> use the Azure cloud shell to ssh into my Linux VM's on Azure, they
>   don't have a public IP and they are on a Virtual Network.

It's **not** possible.

Azure cloud shell is an interactive, browser-accessible shell for managing Azure resource. Works like a VM, can't access Azure VMs without public IP address.